# Not null assertion operator in React

Tags: reactjs

The following error is coming in build time:

```
src/views/contact-page/contact.page.tsx
  Line 25:29:  Parsing error: Missing semicolon.

  23 |   const [test, setTest] = useState<string | null>(null);
  24 |   setTest("test");
> 25 |   const test2: string = test!;
     |                             ^
  26 |
```

Please explain why I could not use not-null assertion operator?

Comment: Check if you have a proper config for build.

Comment: @RyanLe, I'm able to run the project, if I replace the last line above to: const test2 = test; Could you elaborate on how to check a proper config for build

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is valid JS (Or typescript) syntax.

```
  const test2: string = test!;
```

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) for TS doesn't list this anywhere as a valid check for null - you can do something like this with objects but I don't believe you can do this for a variable like this.

```
 let s = e!.name; // Assert that e is non-null and access name
```

Even if that did work, your variable would just be undefined instead of null in the case that `test` was null.

Comment: Please refer the same document (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) [ Non-null assertion operator: 
A new ! post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation x! produces a value of the type of x with null and undefined excluded. ]